# Timetable App for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a timetable setup to work in conjunction with one of my Models. Before I state my question, I will give some context into the problem.

I have a Model called Appointments with the following columns:

```
Name(String)
Start_time(time)
End_time(time)
Appt_Date(date)
```

Now I can have multiple appointments in 1 day.

For Example, let's say I have the following 2 Appointment objects:

```
Appointment 1: 
Name: Makeup Appointment
Start_time: 11:00 am
End_time: 1:00 pm
Date: March 30, 2016

Appointment 2: 
Name: Daily Meetup
Start-time: 2:00 pm
End_time: 3:00 pm
Date: March 30, 2016
```

I would like to implement a date-picker form where you can select a date and it would render 24 rows(1 for each hour of the day) and fill in the rows with the times not available based on the appointments on that day.

For example, if I select March 30, 2016 from the date-picker, I would like to render the 24 rows and have the rows for 11am-1pm and 2:00pm-3:00pm shaded out.

The setup is like google calendars(how time slots are colored in) but with a day-to-day basis. I don't need to be able to edit these rows. I just need to view them and have them rendered with colored cells based on Appointment objects for that specific day.

My issue is, I don't know where to begin to be able to design these 24 rows that interact with appointment objects. I was thinking that perhaps I build a helper method, however even that I am pretty lost. I would appreciate some guidance on how to approach this.

Comment: Why not use `starts_at` and `ends_at`, with both being `datetime` fields for your `Appointments`? There's no point having 3 fields for these ... and this would allow an appointment to potentially span a number of days if required.

Comment: Valid suggestion! I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below will help you:

```
    1.Create  a file in initializer which contains list of available time slots like 10 am to 10 pm.
    2.For displaying date time field , use some jquery date time picker plugin.
    3.Fire an ajax when clicked on datetime picker.
    4.Ajax request will come on the controller & where you have to create an active record query which will fetch all apointments according to the particular date.
    5.MAke an array variable & store the time which are already booked in the above appointments.
    6.Compare the available time with the booked time & edit datetimepikcer.js to shaded the booked date.
```